# Are there any anime/manga that have caused outrage to the point of them being banned in any culture?

Tags: culture, manga-history

I want to know if there is any city/country or culture that has banned any manga/anime because it opposes their beliefs?
I have read articles that say Pokemon  is against Christianity; however, are there any more?

Comment: `I know of Christianity and Pokémon.` I don't; what's that referring to? Maybe you should give a bit more context on that?

Comment: [banned in china](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BannedInChina)

Comment: I assume literally everything is banned in North Korea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ha ha ha ha ha OH YES.

China: Death Note, Code Geass (temporarily), Blood-C, Psycho-Pass, Attack on Titan, Deadman Wonderland [and more](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-06-09/china-blacklists-attack-on-titan-death-note-36-more-anime-manga/.89055) and anything with yaoi content

France: Temporarily banned Kinnikuman for having a heroic character that wore a swastika

Iran: Basically everything is banned unless the Ministry of Islamic Culture approves it (unlikely to happen with anime/manga)

Japan has even banned a few: "Barefoot Gen" and "Midori (Shoujo Tsubaki)"

New Zealand: Highschool DxD and Puni Puni Poemy were banned for 'objectionable material' (To be fair, they also banned Power Rangers, because parents complained that their kids got hurt trying to imitate the show)

Singapore: Anything with yaoi content

And that's just a sampling....

Comment: It'd be nice if you provided some of the sources to this.  Yes, I know too that there were a lot of these that were banned, but having the ability to objectively prove it would go a long way to improving this answer.

Comment: "Japan" has never banned "Barefoot Gen", as far as I'm aware. Some schools did, but this is a completely different issue. Schools ban books all the time (not that this is a _good_ thing, but I don't think it's really noteworthy).

Comment: I'm curious if the places that banned anything Yaoi also banned anything Yuri

Comment: Could I get a source for both the Iran and Singapore answers that you have given. It would help me a lot.

Comment: @HarshMahaseth Iran was based around a google search about the "Ministry of Culture and Islamic Guidance." Singapore's ban is based on Section 377A of the Singapore Penal Code which is a blanket ban on male homosexuality in the country.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I like to state I find your claim `I know of Christianity and Pokémon.`  fairly weird. All though I know in some streams of Christianity it is frowned upon *(speaking as somebody with a religious up-bring)* it never has been out righteously banned for religious reasons, and most likely not by a country/culture as a whole.

Most series don't get banned for opposing religious beliefs. They don't even get aired at all! An example of this would be Iran.

Iran first gives a thorough screening to everything that is aired on television by the Ministry of Islamic Culture. All though they do not allow most anime content, it is not a `ban` *(the act of prohibiting by law)*, but `censorship` *(the practice of officially examining books, movies, etc., and suppressing unacceptable parts)*, which sometimes is the series as a whole.

> Any form of media in Iran needs the permission of the Ministry of Islamic Culture for distribution, which sets an arbitrary array of rules subject to change at any time by the government. These rules include any form of pornography or sexual imagery (particularly centered on the display of the female form, which in the Islam religion, is taboo), political material not in agreement with the government's goals, and any form of communication criticizing Islam. These restrictions are often circumvented by physical and internet piracy, use of satellite dishes and illegal used book markets. [Source - TvTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BannedInChina)

All though there are plenty of censors due to religious reasons. I were unable to find any that out righteously banned a series due to religions reasons.

Comment: When La Pucelle Tactics was localized to the US from Japan anything that references Christianity was removed such as Croix's gun and the spell animations and hell being renamed to The Dark World with the reasons for the change being stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Pucelle:_Tactics#Release) as being religious transgressions. but this is more censorship than banning (though the quote does seem to imply that the game would have been banned if they didn't make the changes)

Comment: @Memor-X It's not censorship if a company chooses to edit their own work voluntarily. If they fear protests or boycotts and make changes to the game to avoid them that's their choice. There's nothing illegal about putting Hell or crosses in a video games, plenty of games have them, so there was nothing stopping them from releasing the game unchanged. It wouldn't have even changed its ESRB rating, which is only concerned about language, violence and nudity.